# Criar uma list com valores selecionados da table com checkbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core

Eu tenho este `código`, que ele pega o `id` selecionado da `table`:

```
 $("#tablepesquisaclientes tr").each(function (index, el) {
var $linha = $(el);
var checked = $linha.find('.checked:checked').length;
if (checked === 1) {
    console.log($linha.find('td').eq(1).text());
}
});
```

Porém eu preciso criar uma lista, para receber no `controller`, já criei a classe, e já declarei no `ViewModel`

```
public class ListaContrato {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

 public IList<ListaContrato> ListaContrato { get; set; }
```

Este é o `html` da minha `table`

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-striped" id="tablepesquisaclientes" style="font-size:12px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Nº Contrato</th>
            <th>Cliente</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Contratos)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="checked"/></td>
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>@item.Cliente.Nome</td>
                <td>@item.Valor.ToString("N2")</td>
                <td style="display:none;">@item.PedidoVenda.EmpresaID</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Como posso passar os valores selecionados para o `controller` ? Tem alguma forma de passar direto para o `controller` criando uma `list`, ou passando apenas por `ajax` ?

Essa é a parte do `controller`, eu queria receber tudo pela `ViewModel` se tivesse jeito.

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EnvioLote(EnviarLoteViewModel model)
```

Tentei criando também conforme a resposta do Leonardo:

```
  public int[] Ids { get; set; }
```

E então no `click` do `button` fazendo assim:

```
 var enviarLote = { Ids: [] };
            $("#tablepesquisaclientes tr").each(function (index, el) {
                var $linha = $(el);
                var checked = $linha.find('.checked:checked').length;
                if (checked === 1) {

                    var id = $linha.find('td').eq(1).text();
                    enviarLote.Ids.push(id);
                    console.log($linha.find('td').eq(1).text());
                }
            });
            console.table(enviarLote);
            $.post("/NFSe/EnvioLote", enviarLote)
                .done(function () {
                    console.log('postado');
                })
                .fail(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log('erro');
                })
                .always(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log('fim');
                });
```

Porém no `controller` os `Ids` continuam `null`.

Comment: Para enviar para o controller, ou vc submete um form ou faz um Ajax.

Comment: Atualmente eu estou fazendo por `submit`, porém como posso fazer para passar esta lista que vou criar quando selecionar o `checkbox` ?

Comment: Coloque um `name` nos checkboxes em forma de array, tipo: `name="ids[]"`... e coloque também um `value` com os ids: `value="@item.Id"`... assim, quando vc submeter, irá receber os valores dos checkboxes marcados em forma de array chamada `ids`.

Comment: @Sam desta forma eu não consegui, ou eu não entendi o conceito, tentei passar com o `ids` e também com a lista que eu criei `ListaContratos[]` porém não passa nenhum tipo de valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que sua model seja assim:

```
public class EnviarLoteViewModel
{
    public int[] Ids { get; set; }
}
```

Esse javascript fará o post.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#enviarBtn").click(function () {

        var enviarLote = { Ids: []};

        $("#tablepesquisaclientes tr").each(function (index, el) {
            var $linha = $(el);
            var checked = $linha.find('.checked:checked').length;
            if (checked === 1) {

                var id = $linha.find('td').eq(1).text();
                enviarLote.Ids.push(id);
                console.log($linha.find('td').eq(1).text());
            }
        });

        $.post("/Home/Enviar", enviarLote)
            .done(function () {
                console.log('postado');
            })
            .fail(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log('erro');
            })
            .always(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log('fim');
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: Eu preciso mostrar esse que eu já mostro, e através dele, criar uma nova lista, com os que foram selecionados pelo `checkbox`

Comment: Fiz a alteração para manter o código javascript que você já tem. ;-)

Comment: Tentei fazer igual você  fez, porém o `Ids` vem `null`, fiz exatamente igual vc deu o exemplo.

Comment: Subi o código aqui - https://github.com/ltreze/questaostackoverflow - Roda aí e me fala, pls.